# Is it possible to inherit a cck into another CCK and assign multiple values to it

Tags: views, 7, entities

I have been searching stackoverflow, drupal forums, drupal.stackexchange for how to create **multiple values** for a **group**. I came across several posts regarding the issue mainly [Drupal Custom CCK field with multiple child fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640534/drupal-custom-cck-field-with-multiple-child-fields)
 and [cck multiple groups](http://drupal.org/node/232184) but I din't find (may be) the exact solution. I even tried **Groups module** but din't understand how to organize fields.

Is it possible to inherit a cck and call that cck into another cck and assign multiple values to it
I know that node reference field type will do this but can i assign multiple values ? 
To be brief:

Now I want to call Asset cck in Events and assign multiple values to it just like eventname- Launching a new iphone

- assetname(title of the pdf)-- iphone 5 introduction   **Text field**
                 pdf(link) -- www.mysite/flder/iphone5intro.pdf   **File type**
- assetname(title of the pdf)-- iphone 5 user manual    **Text field**
                 pdf(link) -- www.mysite/flder/iphone5manual.pdf  **File type**
  etc

It can have multiple values and it should also support **views**

help, and please ignore for any mistakes made, I will be very thankful for any alterations made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first look at this, it seems you are wanting to create a cck content type with a multiple value filefield field so you can upload multiple pdfs per node.

If that is the case, make sure you have the [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) module installed if D6 (it's in core in D7) and then you can, after creating the content type, add a field, select it's type to be File, and then in configure, allow it to have 1,2,...10 or any number of values.

After that, everything "just works," including Views.

Comment: I already have an idea on how to add multiple fields ! My requirement is if i create 3 files in filefields , i would like to attach a filename,description for each appropriate/corresponding file in the file field ?

Comment: where do you want this description displayed?

Comment: example:
Events-->
multiple fields start here 1.pic1
                           2.pic1 name
                           3.pic1 description
next group                 1.pic1
                           2.pic1 name
                           3.pic1 description

Comment: I am really at a loss with that example so maybe distinct content types are the only way to go, just not sure.  Regardless, if you know how to use reference fields, you could create a reference field in your asset type that references an event content type.  Then in a block displayed with your events, you use Views to list all assets with that event referenced with whatever fields you wanted.  This does assume each asset is assigned to only one event.  If this isn't the case, nothing suggests you can't have this be a multi value field.

Comment: Yes. Let me try. Another solution may be field collection module. seems to be handy. any way i will let you know ! I am really happy for your valuable responses they are useful as well.